# Common Lisp processing Structure slots sequentially

Tags: struct, common-lisp

Is there a work-around for structure body slot bindings to be processed in sequence as in `LET*` so that previous slot assignments are visible to later ones?

For instance in the following i want `c` to be visible for `d`.

```
(defstruct (my-struct (:constructor cons-struct (a b)))
  (c (* a b))
  (d c))
```

How could i get this effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already use a [*boa constructor*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defstr.htm).  You can use its [*boa lambda list*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_df.htm) to do things in order:

```
(defstruct (my-struct (:constructor cons-struct (a b
                                                 &aux
                                                  (c (* a b))
                                                  (d c))))
  c
  d)
```